# Export Neo4J Graph to HTML

Tags: html, neo4j, offline

Is it possible to export my Neo4J graph into an HTML file?

I don't need to add or delete existing nodes. I just want my current graph as is in the Neo4j browser, but with the ability to drag it around and select groups without having the neo4j server installed.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a js lib like Sigma or Cytoscape to draw your graph

https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neo_sigma

Answer (score 1):

Just export your graph via Cypher to JSON and then use a simple Javascript function to render those stored Cypher results as JSON that's usable with D3

See here for a step by step guide:

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/

Comment: can we import the results back into a neo4j DB using the browser?